# Textbox in UserControl is locking up the application when height is bound to StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having an odd issue with a UserControl and I'm not sure if it's a bug I should report to MS or if I'm doing something wrong as I'm still learning WPF.

I've got a very basic UserControl which has a textbox and a couple of buttons which are added to a DockPanel:

```
<Border Name="brdrMain" CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2"  Background="Black">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" Name="grdQuery"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="spEditor" Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBox Foreground="AntiqueWhite" IsReadOnly="True" Background="DarkOliveGreen" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" >SQL Editor</TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="tbxQuery" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AcceptsReturn="True" 
                          Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=spEditor}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- buttons -->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,10,5">
            <Button Template="{DynamicResource SaveButtonTemplate1}"  Name="btnSave" IsDefault="True" Margin="10,0,0,0" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Image Source="/Images/savedisk25px.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Foreground="White"  VerticalAlignment="Center">Save</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>

            <Button Template="{DynamicResource CloseButtonTemplate1}"  Name="btnCancel" IsCancel="True" Background="Transparent"  Margin="10,0,0,0" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Image Source="/Images/cancel.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Foreground="White"  VerticalAlignment="Center">Close</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I've got no code behind this XAML:

```
namespace com.MyApp.Controls.LinkageControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for SQLEditor.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SQLEditor : UserControl
    {
        public SQLEditor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

The control adds to the DockPanel just fine:

```
        SQLEditor oSQLEditor = new SQLEditor();
        _dpNavWindow.Children.Add((UIElement)oSQLEditor);
```

I can run the app and the panel opens ok.  And if I click on any of the other objects, other than the tbxQuery the application still responds (I can see it by doing a mouse over on the buttons).

Once I click on the tbxQuery the app is non-responsive and the Process Memory in VS2019 counts up really fast.

This is the first time I'm dynamically setting the height in a control so I set the Height of the control to a fixed number and the lockup went away so it appears that the Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=spEditor}" in the TextBox control is what is causing the problem.  However, I need this control to expand to fill the area if the window is resized.

Does anyone know why this is occurring and/or how to get around it?

This is the control:

[image: Custom control]

Comment: This smells like an infinite loop: when you click the box it changes it's size, that changes the stack size, that makes the textbox to resize again, which resizes the stack and so on.

Comment: see what happens when you put `Mode="OneWay"` in binding. like `Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=spEditor, Mode="OneWay"}"/>`

Comment: It no longer counts up on memory but the app still locks with mode="OneWay"

Comment: You don't usually bind the Width or Height properties of UI elements to that of its parents. Use a proper layout instead. If you'd tell us how it is supposed to look, you may perhaps be able to help you.

Comment: Remove the extra `StackPanel` parent of `spEditor` and also, just for test also remove the another `TextBlock` (as `spEditor` has two childern) and check what happens ?

Comment: I did, code is updated above.  Same thing is happening...

Comment: You didn't do exactly what i said ! i also asked you to remove other `TextBox` and it turns out after trying your code i'ts the other `TextBox` causing this issue.

Comment: the reason seems to me is simple. One `TextBox` is taking i'ts space as it should while to other `TextBox` you are saying that you take all the space available by binding to their mutual parent's height. So the `tbxQuery` will try take all the space but then where will other textBox go ? UI is stuck because of this issue (i guess)... further sir @Clemens may tell.

Comment: @Clemens Sorry, just saw your comment now.  I have a title bar across the top, a multi-line textbox, then two buttons at the bottom of the screen. I need the textbox to resize in the DockPanel.  I'll put the image above so you can see it.

Comment: @RaoHammas even if I remove the first textbox, the problem still persists...

Comment: @Zonus well i've tried your `XAML` and it doesn't ! problem occurs only when two textboxes are children of StackPanel.

Comment: Weird, perhaps I did it wrong previously. But I tried it again and you're right.  I made another grid row and placed that first textbox in the first row, the second in the second, and the buttons in the 3rd and it's working now! Thanks man!

Comment: Great ! the UI layOut you are tryig to implement can be done using just one `Grid` easily so don't use these extra `StackPanel`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never need Width or Height bindings as replacement for proper layout.

One example:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextAlignment="Center" Text="SQL Editor"/>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Content="Save"/>
        <Button Content="Close"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Another one:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="SQL Editor"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Content="Save"/>
        <Button Content="Close"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I wish you had answered a bunch of other questions on here about how to autosize a textbox! I was thinking the same thing prior to reading those questions and answers.  This is by far the cleanest way to do it!